# Want to find $A\subseteq M$ such that $(\partial A)^\circ = M$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

$(M,d)$ is a metric space. I have been asked to produce $A\subseteq M$, such that $$(\partial A)^\circ  = M$$

---

Could someone help me find such a set? Here are my thoughts so far:

We want to find $A\subseteq M$ such that $(\partial A)^\circ = M$. For all $x\in A$ gives $x\in M$ and hence $x\in (\partial A)^\circ$. $x\in (\partial A)^\circ$ means that $x\in \partial A$ and there exists $r_x > 0$ such that $B(x,r_x) \subseteq \partial A$. $x\in\partial A$ additionally gives $B(x,r_x)\cap A\neq\emptyset$ and $B(x,r_x)\cap A^c\neq\emptyset$. We get $\partial A\cap A \neq \emptyset$ and $\partial A\cap A^c\neq \emptyset$. All this is good - but how do I find some $A$ that satisfies these properties?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not $\Bbb{Q} \subseteq \Bbb{R}$? The interior operation seems redundant; unless I'm missing something, this will be satisfied if and only if $\partial A = M$.

Comment: Just to clarify, $(\mathbb Q)^\circ = \emptyset$ right? No matter what $x\in\mathbb Q$ you pick, an $\epsilon$-ball centered at $x$ will include irrationals (for every $\epsilon$)!

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Oh wait, it seems I misinterpreted. We have to find $\partial\mathbb Q$ first, and then think about its interior. What's $\partial\mathbb Q$?

Comment: We are talking about the boundary of $\Bbb{Q}$ right? It's equal to $\overline{\Bbb{Q}} \setminus \Bbb{Q}^\circ = \Bbb{R} \setminus \emptyset = \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Yeah, the boundary. I see, this works - $\partial \mathbb Q = \mathbb R$ and $(\mathbb R)^\circ  =\mathbb R$ itself!

Comment: Yep! I would have put this in an answer, but the presence of the interior threw me, since it's redundant. I thought there might be something I was missing.

Comment: The interior of $\partial A$ is $M$ iff $\partial A=M$ iff $A^\circ = \emptyset$ and $\overline{A}=M$. So you need a dense set with empty interior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** find such $A$ for all metric spaces, as $(\partial A)^\circ = M$ iff $\partial A = M$ iff $\overline{A}=M$ (so $A$ is dense) **and** $A^\circ = \emptyset$. So if $M$ has an isolated point, this point is in all dense sets and in their interior too, so no such $A$ can exist. E.g. in a set with the discrete metric all subsets $A$ have $\partial A = \emptyset$. It is well-known that *if* $M$ has no isolated points, such an $A$ does always exist; then we can split $M$ into two disjoint dense subsets and each of them well do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Theo Bendit for their answer in the comments. Just adding it here for documentation. On the metric space $\mathbb R$ with the usual metric, consider $\mathbb Q$. Then,
$$(\partial \mathbb Q)^\circ = \mathbb R$$
since $$\partial\mathbb Q = \mathbb R \text{ and } \mathbb R^\circ = \mathbb R$$

Comment: One specific example for one space is *not* a proof for the general case..